# Alterar texto no site de acordo com o horário

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Fazer uma variável para cada dia.
 Uma função que se estiver no dia da semana X buscar horarios abertos. 
Comparar horario de funcionamento com a hora atual
mostrar resultado.

```
<p>Estamos abertos</p>
<p>Estamos fechados</p>
```

**INFORMAÇÕES:**
**segunda**: 
8 as 14-> aberto 
16 as 23-> aberto 
intervalo -> fechado
**terça: ...**

isso seria mais fácil e viável fazer em Jquery, Javascript ou PHP ?

E como seria ?

Comment: jQuery é uma biblioteca, não uma linguagem, o Javascript é usado no lado do cliente, já o PHP no servidor, então use o PHP. Você já tem algum código iniciado?

Comment: um problema lógico nisso é que depende do browser do visitante. Se o PC do visitante estiver com data e horários errados, as mensagens aparecerão erradas.. Outro ponto é visitantes de fuso horário diferente. O mais seguro é obter a data e horário no próprio servidor  e, obviamente, adatetime do server deve estar correto e de acordo com o fuso horário local..

Answer (score 2):

jQuery é JavaScript, é uma biblioteca com um conjunto de funcionalidades escritas em JavaScript.

Eu faria isso no lado do servidor, em PHP. Porque é melhor ter o HTML feito quando sai do servidor e porque o servidor tem sempre a mesma hora interna. Se fizeres em JavaScript tens de saber a hora do cliente (fuso horário) e adaptar, vai dar mais trabalho.

Deixo um exemplo em PHP. Criei uma array com alguns dias (tens de completar o resto). Depois itero essa array onde o `$i` é o dia da semana a comparar com `date('w');`. Provavelmente tens de ajustar a hora do servidor com a tua hora local. Podes fazer isso aqui: `$hora = intval(date('h')) +/- x horas;`.

Exemplo:

```
$horario = array(
   0 => array('weekday'=> 'Segunda', 'open'=>array(array(8, 14), array(16, 23))),
    1 => array('weekday'=> 'Terça', 'open'=>array(array(8, 14), array(16, 23))),
    2 => array('weekday'=> 'Quarta', 'open'=>array(array(8, 14), array(16, 23)))
);
$dia_semana = date('w');
$hora = intval(date('h'));
$status = 'Fechado';

$html = '<h3>Informações</h3>';
for($i = 0; $i < count($horario); $i++){
    $dia = $horario[$i];

    $html.= "<h4>".$dia['weekday']."</h4>";
  foreach($dia['open'] as $horas){
      if ($dia_semana == $i && $hora > $horas[0] && $hora < $horas[1]) $status = 'Aberto';
    $html.= "<p>".$horas[0]." - ".$horas[1]."</p>";
    }
}
$html.= "<p><strong>".$status."</strong></p>";
echo $html;
```

#### Exemplo online: https://ideone.com/Cz90Ft

Comment: Vou testar, e atualizo.

Comment: @manzetti.denis conseguiste pôr isto a funcionar?

Answer (score -1):

Use esse acho q te atende.

Codigo:

```
<script language=javascript type="text/javascript">
            
            now = new Date
            
            if (now.getDay () > 0 && now.getDay() < 2 ) if (now.getHours () >= 0 && now.getHours () < 08)
            
            {document.write ("<font face='verdana', arial' size=2 color='red'><b>Fechado</b>")}
            
            else if (now.getDay () > 0 && now.getDay() < 2 ) if (now.getHours () >= 09 && now.getHours () < 17)
            
            {document.write ("<font face='verdana', arial' size=2 color='#40f907'><b>Aberto</b>")}
            
            else if (now.getDay () > 0 && now.getDay() < 2 ) if (now.getHours () >= 18 && now.getHours () < 23)
            
            {document.write ("<font face='verdana', arial' size=2 color='Red'><b>Fechado</b>")}
            
            
            
                                     //TERÇA - FEIRA
            
            if (now.getDay () > 1 && now.getDay() < 3 ) if (now.getHours () >= 0 && now.getHours () < 08)
            
            {document.write ("<font face='verdana', arial' size=2 color='red'><b>Fechado</b>")}
            
            else if (now.getDay () > 1 && now.getDay() < 3 ) if (now.getHours () >= 09 && now.getHours () < 17)
            
            {document.write ("<font face='verdana', arial' size=2 color='#40f907'><b>Aberto</b>")}
            
            else if (now.getDay () > 1 && now.getDay() < 3 ) if (now.getHours () >= 18 && now.getHours () < 23)
            
            {document.write ("<font face='verdana', arial' size=2 color='Red'><b>Fechado</b>")}
            
            
            
                                     //QUARTA - FEIRA
            
            if (now.getDay () > 2 && now.getDay() < 4 ) if (now.getHours () >= 0 && now.getHours () < 08)
            
            {document.write ("<font face='verdana', arial' size=2 color='red'><b>Fechado</b>")}
            
            else if (now.getDay () > 2 && now.getDay() < 4 ) if (now.getHours () >= 09 && now.getHours () < 17)
            
            {document.write ("<font face='verdana', arial' size=2 color='red'><b>Fechado</b>")}
            
            else if (now.getDay () > 2 && now.getDay() < 4 ) if (now.getHours () >= 18 && now.getHours () < 23)
            
            {document.write ("<font face='verdana', arial' size=2 color='#40f907'><b>Aberto</b>")}
            
            
            
                                     //QUINTA - FEIRA
            
            if (now.getDay () > 3 && now.getDay() < 5 ) if (now.getHours () >= 0 && now.getHours () < 08)
            
            {document.write ("<font face='verdana', arial' size=2 color='red'><b>Fechado</b>")}
            
            else if (now.getDay () > 3 && now.getDay() < 5 ) if (now.getHours () >= 09 && now.getHours () < 17)
            
            {document.write ("<font face='verdana', arial' size=2 color='#40f907'><b>Aberto</b>")}
            
            else if (now.getDay () > 3 && now.getDay() < 5 ) if (now.getHours () >= 18 && now.getHours () < 23)
            
            {document.write ("<font face='verdana', arial' size=2 color='red'><b>Fechado</b>")}
            
            
            
                                     //SEXTA - FEIRA
            
            if (now.getDay () > 4 && now.getDay() < 6 ) if (now.getHours () >= 0 && now.getHours () < 07)
            
            {document.write ("<font face='verdana', arial' size=2 color='red'><b>Fechado</b>")}
            
            else if (now.getDay () > 4 && now.getDay() < 6 ) if (now.getHours () >= 08 && now.getHours () < 17)
            
            {document.write ("<font face='verdana', arial' size=2 color='red'><b>Fechado</b>")}
            
            else if (now.getDay () > 3 && now.getDay() < 5 ) if (now.getHours () >= 18 && now.getHours () < 23)
            
            {document.write ("<font face='verdana', arial' size=2 color='#40f907'><b>Aberto</b>")}
            
            
            
                                     //SABADO
            
            if (now.getDay () > 5 && now.getDay() < 7 ) if (now.getHours () >= 0 && now.getHours () < 07)
            
            {document.write ("<font face='verdana', arial' size=2 color='red'><b>Fechado</b>")}
            
            else if (now.getDay () > 5 && now.getDay() < 7 ) if (now.getHours () >= 08 && now.getHours () < 17)
            
            {document.write ("<font face='verdana', arial' size=2 color='red'><b>Fechado</b>")}
            
            else if (now.getDay () > 5 && now.getDay() < 7 ) if (now.getHours () >= 18 && now.getHours () < 23)
            
            {document.write ("<font face='verdana', arial' size=2 color='#40f907'><b>Aberto</b>")}
            
            
            
                                     //DOMING0
            
            if (now.getDay () > 0,99 && now.getDay() < 1 ) if (now.getHours () >= 0 && now.getHours () < 07)
            
            {document.write ("<font face='verdana', arial' size=2 color='red'><b>Fechado</b>")}
            
            else if (now.getDay () > 0,99 && now.getDay() < 1 ) if (now.getHours () >= 08 && now.getHours () < 13)
            
            {document.write ("<font face='verdana', arial' size=2 color='#40f907'><b>Aberto</b>")}
            
            else if (now.getDay () > 0,99 && now.getDay() < 1 ) if (now.getHours () >= 14 && now.getHours () < 23)
            
            {document.write ("<font face='verdana', arial' size=2 color='Red'><b>Fechado</b>")}
            
            </script>
```